# Max-height, with Calc vh in Safari

Tags: css, safari, viewport-units, css-calc

For Safari the following is not working, can anyone pinpoint in what I'm doing wrong?

```
max-height: calc(80vh - 140px);
```

All methods are individually supported on Safari. -webkit-calc doesn't help either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be part of a [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94158) reported om Chrome browsers, since Safari also uses the Webkit engine.

Comment: Thanks. Though, this was fixed in May, I guess this shouldve been pushed by now?